# ParseUser SignupInBackground method always returns ParseException (TypeError)

Tags: android, parse-platform

I have a subclass of `ParseUser`, which has the following method:

```
void Register(String email, final String password, final EditText[] inputs){
    final CRUser user = new CRUser(this, email, password, null, null);

    user.signUpInBackground(new SignUpCallback() {
        @Override
        public void done(ParseException e) {
            hideProgressToast(e == null);
            if (e == null) {
                doRegistrationRelatedTasks(user, password);
            } else {
                handleRegistrationError("Failed to Register", ParseExceptionWrapper.getErrorMessageForRegistrationError(e), inputs);
                AppDebugLogWriter.dumpException(e);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

The constructor used looks like this:

```
public CRUser(Context context, String email, String password, String firstName, String lastName)
{
    super();

    setEmail(email);
    setUsername(email);
    setFirstName(firstName);
    setLastName(lastName);
    setPassword(password);
}
```

This code was working perfectly for 6+ months but suddenly stopped working. And now it returns a `ParseException` in the callback. Here's the StackTrace:

```
reason: TypeError: Cannot read property 'facebook' of undefined
 at Object.Validation.validateValuesExist.success (objects/user.js:222:28)
 at Object.exports.validateValuesExist (service/validation.js:21:18)
 at Object.exports.handleBeforeSave (objects/user.js:201:16)
 at main.js:338:19
com.parse.ParseRequest$ParseRequestException: TypeError: Cannot read property 'facebook' of undefined
 at Object.Validation.validateValuesExist.success (objects/user.js:222:28)
 at Object.exports.validateValuesExist (service/validation.js:21:18)
 at Object.exports.handleBeforeSave (objects/user.js:201:16)
 at main.js:338:19
 at com.parse.ParseRequest.newPermanentException(ParseRequest.java:391)
 at com.parse.ParseRESTCommand.onResponse(ParseRESTCommand.java:197)
 at com.parse.ParseRESTUserCommand.onResponse(ParseRESTUserCommand.java:114)
 at com.parse.ParseRequest$3.then(ParseRequest.java:258)
 at com.parse.ParseRequest$3.then(ParseRequest.java:254)
 at bolts.Task$10.run(Task.java:486)
 at bolts.BoltsExecutors$ImmediateExecutor.execute(BoltsExecutors.java:97)
 at bolts.Task.completeAfterTask(Task.java:482)
 at bolts.Task.continueWithTask(Task.java:358)
 at bolts.Task.continueWithTask(Task.java:369)
 at bolts.Task$8.then(Task.java:415)
 at bolts.Task$8.then(Task.java:407)
 at bolts.Task$10.run(Task.java:486)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

The same error occurs on iOS too.

Comment: `doRegistrationRelatedTasks(user, password);` ??. post more code and  have you wrote any cloud code?

Comment: @kishorejethava the code in `doRegistrationRelatedTasks(user, password)` never executes, the `else` block gets executed.

Comment: Can you show your AndroidManifest file?

Comment: @Ralphilius what are we looking for? Its a pretty long file, rather not post the whole thing here. I have double checked and all the Parse related stuff (permissions, broadcast receivers, services etc.) are there correctly.

Comment: What is `main.js:338:19`? Are you developing native android app or Phonegap or anything?

Comment: @Ralphilius Its a native Android app. main.js must be a file on Parse's server API implementation.

Comment: Do you have any cloud code implementation?

Comment: @Ralphilius I have cloud code implementations, but the code where the crash occurs doesn't execute any of those.

Comment: @Ralphilius You were right the error was occurring in cloud code. Thanks.